# Finding Local mean value of pixels of window

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, local-features

I want to solve the equation (2) in the attached picture which tells the local mean value. But i don't have any idea about how to evaluate this equation using matlab code. could only guess w indicates window size. What does g(m,n) means? Can anyone please help me to understand this concept?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is nothing to solve here. Equation 2 is a definition of $\bar{g}$. All you need to do is to evaluate it.

Comment: yes i dont have any idea about how to evaluate it.

Comment: @EmersonEJ, Could you review my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a filter which calculates the mean.

In MATLAB you can achieve this using:

```matlab
mK = ones(w, w) / (w * w);
mGBar = imfilter(mG, mK);
```

Basically the value of `mGBar(m, n)` equals to the mean value of a window of size `wxw` centered at `mG(m, n)`.